# using the midiio interface (linux) with a usb midi controller

Tags: linux, input, usb, midi

I want to read MIDI input from a USB MIDI-controller on linux.
 
I found this set of libraries here http://midiio.sapp.org/, but I don't know whether it will support USB MIDI devices (can't test this until next month, don't have the hardware yet).
Does anyone have some experience with midiio or, alternatively, can anyone recommand another well documented MIDI library which will specifically support USB devices?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Midiio can use ALSA under Linux, so I would venture to guess that it will work provided the MIDI device is supported by ALSA.